# chartjs how to show the sf symbol on the x axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to show the image icon with the letter on the X-axis.

I tried two ways for it: the first one is to paste a 4-letter Unicode string of the Unicode image to labels, and the second one is to use the SF symbol image.

For the second way, I copied the value of the SF symbol from the SF symbols app on the macOS and pasted the value on the following code.
As the result, the SF symbol is shown on Google Chrome, but it does not work on the Safari browser.

How to solve it?

```
Chart.defaults.font.family = "'SF Pro'";
const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Sun \u2600', 'Mon ', 'Tue', 'Wed \u263E', 'Thr', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
...
```

'Mon ' is the value of the SF symbol copied from the SF symbols app.

[screenshot on Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO0id.png)

Comment: It appears to work for me using "SF Pro".  Using the Unicode char value above, the value `\u2600` prints properly in Safari with Chart.js 3.9.1.  I did my test using a ticks `callback` -- `ticks: {callback: (v, i) => {return [" ", "off \u2600", "on \u2600", " "][i]}},`  You might try setting the tick labels with a callback and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks, DaveL17. How about `Mon `?  Is it also working?

Comment: The character you're interested in doesn't show up on my system.  Please provide the `\u` code (explicitly) and I'll be happy to test it.  Is it `\u263E`?